# How to create a RESTful application using Jersey and Mustache template engine?

Tags: java, jersey, mustache

**Edit** My initial problem was that I was not using the correct version of jersey. So, I made changes and kept the previous question for future reference. However, if you are using `Jersey 2.x`, please go to the **Update** header in this question.

I am trying to write a simple web application using Jersey and Mustache, running on Jetty. For building the project, I am using Gradle.

Here is my buildfile.

```
apply plugin: 'jetty'

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

dependencies {
   providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
   runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'

   compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1'
   compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17.1'            
   compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.17.1'

   compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-mustache:2.3.1'
}

httpPort = 8080
stopPort = 9080
stopKey = "stopKey"
```

and my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>XPoViz</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.webapp</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.mustache.MustacheMvcFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and I have a simple controller class

```
package com.example.webapp;

@Path("login")
public class Login {
    @Context
    private SecurityContext context;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Viewable get(){
        return new Viewable("index", "FOO");
    }
}
```

In the same package (com.example.webapp) I have created a mustache file called `index.mustache` which is a simple HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple mustache test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is mustacheee</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I do `gradle jettyRun` it starts the server. However, when I try to access the login path, it raises `500` error and I see the following error on my console

> A message body writer for Java class
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable, and Java type class
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable, and MIME media type
>   application/xml was not found

As I am new to Java EE web development and Jersey and Jersey-MVC, I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

**Update** After fixing the jersey version

I was using old version of Jersey. So, now the build.gradle updated

```
apply plugin: 'jetty'


jettyRun {
    reload = "automatic"
    scanIntervalSeconds = 1
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

dependencies {      
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.17'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.17'

    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-jsp:2.17'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-mustache:2.17'
}

httpPort = 8080
stopPort = 9080
stopKey = "stopKey"
```

Also, I decided to use ResourceConfig. So my `web.xml` changes to

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>XPoViz</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.webapp.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is MyApplication

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        // Add a package used to scan for components.
        packages(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        register(MustacheMvcFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Now, I have a class/resource that should serve using Mustache. It is :

```
@Path("/mustache")
public class MustacheTest {

    @GET
    @Template(name = "/index.mustache")
    public String get(){
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

I also added the `index.mustache` file in the `WEB-INF` directory. However, when I access **http://localhost:8080/Backend/mustache**, it gives me a `404` (Note: when I run `gradle jettyRunWar`, the web app is deployed at localhost:8080/Backend)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried @Produces({"text/html”}) ? Also you could try changing "index" to "/index"

Comment: It gives the same error, just replacing the mime type in the error

Comment: Is the dependency a typo in your gradle file? It shows jsp

Comment: No i was actually trying jsp if that works (hoping that it should be supported better :P ) When I tried it also had mustache

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-mustache:2.3.1'
```

That's a Jersey 2.x module. You are using Jersey 1.x. These two major versions are incompatible. Registering the feature does nothing.

Now Jersey 1.x comes with the MVC support without any extension modules. The dependencies you have are sufficient. The `Viewable` class though is actually

```
com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable
```

You're using the Jersey 2.x `org.glassfish` one.

But this doesn't solve the problem about using Mustache. Currently from I can tell by looking at [the different extension modules](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/contribs), I don't see any support for Mustache, only Freemarker. I don't know, but you may need to switch to Jersey 2.x if you want to use the Mustache support, unless there is a 1.x implementation somewhere out there I'm unaware of.

Comment: thanks, it turns out I was following a very old example. I switched to jersey 2.x and getting some other issues now. I will update my question now